# Simultaneous/Concurrent RSpec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, tdd, bdd

I know minitest has `parallelize_me!, but I can't seem to find something similar in RSpec.

I need to test a transaction lock.

How is this achieved in RSpec?